# Can I implement a class with variables in java?

Tags: java, berkeley-db-je

Can I implement class using variables like:

```
String classname = "VarClass";
String type1 = "int";
String name1 = "id";
String type2 = "char";
String typesize2 = "(5)"
String name2= "name"

public class classname{
  type1 name1;
  type2 name2;
}
```

I am implementing sort of dynamic class with Base API in BDB je & java.util

Whenever "create table tbname(attname1 atttype1, attname2 atttype2, ...)" command comes in,

Define different class that returns proper object

Is this possible?

Or can anyone help me with this : 
-Guide to Berkeley DB for SQL Developers(https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/seltzer-berkeleydb-sql-086752.html) says that

```
CREATE TABLE employee
        (primary key empid int(8), last_name varchar(20), first_name varchar(15),
        salary numeric(10, 2) salary, street varchar (20), city varchar (15),
        state char(2), zip int(5))
```

turn into this key and data object

```
typedef int emp_key;

typedef struct _emp_data {
        char    lname[20];
        char    fname[15];
        float   salary;
        char    street[20];
        char    city[15];
        char    state[2];
        int     zip;
} emp_data;
//This is implemented in C/C++ language
```

But when there are multiple create commands that each defines different table with different attributes and different number of attribute what should I do?

Is there any way to program this

Comment: I'd take a look at something like [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io)